# How to get the XML root element with its attributes, but without the content

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, marklogic

XML:

```
  <Parent id='1' name='Parent_1'>
    <Children name='Children'>
      <child name='Child_2' id='2'>child2_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_4' id='4'>child4_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_1' id='3'>child1_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_3' id='1'>child3_Parent_1</child>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
```

Expected Output:

```
 <Parent id='1' name='Parent_1'>
```

Hi I have given some sample XML. I have tried with X Query for getting result but I cant identify . Can you please help someone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with a computed element constructor, the content of which only repopulates the attributes.

```
let $root := (: the document, copy-pasted below :)
  <Parent id='1' name='Parent_1'>
    <Children name='Children'>
      <child name='Child_2' id='2'>child2_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_4' id='4'>child4_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_1' id='3'>child1_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_3' id='1'>child3_Parent_1</child>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
return element { node-name($root) } { $root/@* }
```

Additional content can also be inserted into this element like so:

```
let $root := (: the document, copy-pasted below :)
  <Parent id='1' name='Parent_1'>
    <Children name='Children'>
      <child name='Child_2' id='2'>child2_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_4' id='4'>child4_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_1' id='3'>child1_Parent_1</child>
      <child name='Child_3' id='1'>child3_Parent_1</child>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
return element { node-name($root) } {
  $root/@*,
  <foo/>,
  <bar/>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ghislain ..But I got the following error  "Cannot use () as an element name"

Comment: Solved the issue ..Thanks Again

Comment: HI , How get end tag like "</Parent>" , kindly do the needful.

Comment: Hi Antony. If there is no content, then <Parent id='1' name='Parent_1'/> (slash at the end) is equivalent to <Parent id='1' name='Parent_1'></Parent>. XQuery will take care of making sure that the tag is properly closed when it serializes the new element back to XML.

Comment: Hi , I need without close tag (/) . My expectation is <Parent id='1' name='Parent_1'> because I have append some contents and close </Parent> tag finally .

Comment: It is recommended to use tools that produce well-formed XML (XQuery, XSLT, MarkLogic, etc) to manipulate XML. XQuery can also take care of adding content (with a nested query, as shown in the edited answer) inside a tag and of closing it. Otherwise, there is no guarantee in the data flow that the produced document will be well-formed and that it will be consumed properly. It is of course possible to see the XML document as being simply text and use, say, regular expressions to remove the slash and append a closing tag with another language, but this is very risky and beyond XQuery.